# Application happend unavailable parameter in excute runtime

Tags: function, mfc, dialog, installshield

After Install shield, I create a application complete and I excute it,

But something like follow picture. I cant debug it, and I cant fint the error what happend.

Someone can tell me, what method to solve it...

1) Like function parameter no use?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find a rule.

When run the application, the OnCommand Function is early than OnInitDialog function,

the OnCommand will handle static, buttom, listcontrol, color etc.

but My initial variable is in OninitDialog,

So it will append this result.

The solution is declare a variable to avoid into the function, when complete the OninitDialog.